# How can I change google map v2 default red marker color to black in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I change the color of the marker using this function

```
mMap.addMarker(
    new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
);
```

I can't find HUE_BLACK. How can I set the marker color to black? I prefer to avoid custom drawable.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to make a marker

```
  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng( latitude,longitude))
            .title("This is my title")
            .snippet("and snippet")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
```

**and these are the constants you can use**

```
float   HUE_AZURE
float   HUE_BLUE
float   HUE_CYAN
float   HUE_GREEN
float   HUE_MAGENTA
float   HUE_ORANGE
float   HUE_RED
float   HUE_ROSE
float   HUE_VIOLET
float   HUE_YELLOW
```

**thats what is says**
[click here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this way?

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                                       .visible(true).snippet(String.valueOf(i))
                                       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(changeBitmapColor(color))));



private Bitmap changeBitmapColor(int color) {

        Bitmap ob = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.pin_fill);
        Bitmap obm = Bitmap.createBitmap(ob.getWidth(), ob.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Bitmap overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.pin_trans);
        Bitmap overlaym = Bitmap.createBitmap(overlay.getWidth(), overlay.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlaym);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
        canvas.drawBitmap(ob, 0f, 0f, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0f, 0f, null);
        return overlaym;
    }
```

Comment: While using the above method and there are a lot of markers like 300-400 map lags while dragging or loading.

Comment: @Kaushik Chatterjee What parameter you pass as `.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(changeBitmapColor(color))` `color` value ??